# Dependency not resolving correctly in ktor kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

My project is having issues correctly resolving my KGraphql dependency when I try to install the `feature` in my `ktor` project. How do I go about troubleshooting this? Here's the exactly code where it breaks:

```
fun Application.configureGraphql() {

    install(GraphQL) { // cannot resolve graphql here even though it can resolve all the other references to the kgraphql library
        useDefaultPrettyPrinter = true
        playground = true
        endpoint = "/"

        wrap {
            authenticate(optional = true, build = it)
        }

        schema { schema() }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a dependency defined for a GraphQL Ktor plugin https://kgraphql.io/Plugins/ktor/?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that KGraphQL has a bad compatibility  with Ktor 2.0.0 version. I had same problem and downgraded to previous version of Ktor, it worked.

Comment: There is temporary solution

https://github.com/aPureBase/KGraphQL/issues/185